# how can I filter map entries based on set of entries

Tags: java, dictionary, set, guava, predicate

I'm using google guava 12 and have a map:

```
Map<OccupancyType, BigDecimal> roomPrice;
```

I have a Set:

```
Set<OccupancyType> policy;
```

How can I filter entries in the `roomPrice map` based on `policy` and return the filtered map ?

`filteredMap` needs to have all the values from `policy`. In case, roomPrice map doesnt have an entry from policy, I'd like to input default value instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the best way to get a sub HashMap based on a list of Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856781/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-sub-hashmap-based-on-a-list-of-keys)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since you have a Set of keys you should use [Maps.filterkeys()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#filterKeys%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29), also Guava provides a pretty good set of predicates that you can use out of the box. In your case something like [Predicates.in()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#in%28java.util.Collection%29) should work.

So basically you end up with:

```
Map<OccupancyType, BigDecimal> filteredMap
    = Maps.filterKeys(roomPrice, Predicates.in(policy));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still very new to Predicates and not sure how it will generate a predicate that would work upon my map. ALso, is there any way to ensure, filteredMap should have all the values from policy. In case, roomPrice map doesnt have an entry from policy, I'd like to input default value instead.

Comment: If you have a map with "default" entries you can do something like: filteredMap.putAll(Maps.difference(filteredMap, defaultMap).entriesOnlyOnRight());

Comment: Also, you can take a look at this article: http://scaramoche.blogspot.de/2010/08/googles-guava-library-tutorial-part-4.html It has some nice examples of Predicate usage.

Comment: Maps.filterKeys() is often a bad solution because it produces a liveView of the original Map with complexity O(n) for methods like contains() or size(). Better use answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856781

Answer (score 2):

- Override and implement [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashcode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) in
  `OccupancyType`.
- Loop through `roomPrice`'s keyset and collect the
  elements contained in the filter.

Something like this:

```
Map<OccupancyType, BigDecimal> filteredPrices = new HashMap<OccupancyType, BigDecimal>();
for(OccupancyType key : roomPrice.keySet()) {
    if(policy.contains(key) {
        filteredPrices.put(key, roomPrice.get(key));
    }
}
```

**Update**

Ok after reading up a bit on Google Guava, you should be able to do something like:

```
Predicate<OccupancyType> priceFilter = new Predicate<OccupancyType>() {
    public boolean apply(OccupancyType i) {
        return policy.contains(i);
    }
};
```

and then

```
return Maps.filterValues(roomPrice, priceFlter);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! I know that'd work, but am also learning to use guava. I was hoping to use something of the sorts of Maps.filterEntries(...)[link](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#filterEntries(java.util.Map, com.google.common.base.Predicate))[/link] from google-guava. Would you happen to have any ideas how I could do the above with that ?

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer after reading up on that a bit let me know if it works!

Comment: Don't you think it should be `Maps.filterEntries(roomPrice, priceFilter);`

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Guava, also Maps.filterKeys() can produce a result with **very bad performance** for large Maps.

```
// (new map can be initialized to better value to avoid resizing)
Map<OccupancyType, BigDecimal> filteredMap = new HashMap<>(roomPrice.size());
for (OccupancyType key: policy) {
    // contains() and get() can usually be combined
    if (roomPrice.contains(key)) {
       filteredMap.put(key, roomPrice.get(key));
    }
}
```