# what is the best way to get a sub HashMap based on a list of Keys?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap and I would like to get a new HashMap that contains only the elements from the first HashMap where K belongs to a specific List.

I could look through all the keys and fillup a new HashMap but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 36):

With Java8 streams, there is a functional (elegant) solution. If `keys` is the list of keys to keep and `map` is the source `Map`.

```
keys.stream()
    .filter(map::containsKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), map::get));
```

Complete example:

```
    List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    keys.add(2);
    keys.add(3);
    keys.add(42); // this key is not in the map

    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1, "foo");
    map.put(2, "bar");
    map.put(3, "fizz");
    map.put(4, "buz");

    Map<Integer, String> res = keys.stream()
        .filter(map::containsKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), map::get));

    System.out.println(res.toString());
```

Prints: `{2=bar, 3=fizz}`

**EDIT** add a `filter` for keys that are absent from the map

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if you comment out the line `map.put(2, "bar");` you get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 12):

Yes there is a solution:

```
Map<K,V> myMap = ...;
List<K> keysToRetain = ...;
myMap.keySet().retainAll(keysToRetain);
```

The `retainAll` operation on the `Set` updates the underlying map. See [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

**Edit**
Be aware this solution modify the `Map`.

Comment: But he asked for a *new* `HashMap`.

Comment: @KrishPrabakar So just copy the original map by passing it to the constructor of a second map: `Map<K,V> map2 = new HashMap<>( myMap );`. Then call `map2.retainAll( keysToRetain );`

Answer (score 6):

With a help of Guava.

Suppose you have a map `Map<String, String>` and want to submap with a values from `List<String>` list.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("1", "1");
map.put("2", "2");
map.put("3", "4");

final List<String> list = Arrays.asList("2", "4");

Map<String, String> subMap = Maps.filterValues(
                map, Predicates.in(list));
```

Update / Note: As @assylias mentioned in the comment, you will have O(n) when using `contains()`. So if you have large list, this could have huge impact in performance.

On the other side `HashSet.contains()` is constant time O(1), so if there is a possibility to have Set instead of List, this could be a nice approach (**note** that converting List to Set will cost O(n) anyway, so better not to convert :))

Comment: Same comment as for the view: this could be awfully slow if the list is large-ish.

Comment: Very good point. Updated my answer to mention the performance impact on huge lists.

Comment: I'd love to use Guava on this project but I can't. Also the solution is interesting but I'd like to know if there is a solution without external library.

Comment: The question is about filtering based on keys, not values, so Maps.filterKeys() would be correct.

Answer (score 5):

If you have Map m1 and List keys, then try following

```
Map m2 = new HashMap(m1);
m2.keySet().retainAll(keys);
```

Comment: @tkruse That's literally what this is doing by using the `HashMap` copy constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your usage, this may be a more efficient implementation

```
public class MapView implements Map{
  List ak;
  Map map;
  public MapView(Map map, List allowableKeys) {
     ak = allowableKeys;
     map = map;
  }
  public Object get(Object key) {
    if (!ak.contains(key)) return null;
    return map.get(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: `ak.contains` is O(n) vs O(1) if a new map is used instead of a view - that could be an issue.

Comment: The result MapView is not a HashMap, not even a Map.

Answer (score 1):

If your keys have an ordering, you can use a TreeMap.

Look at `TreeMap.subMap()`

It does not let you do this using a list, though.

Comment: Also the @OP specified a HashMap. You're talking about a TreeMap

Answer (score 1):

Copy the map and remove all keys not in the list:

```
Map map2 = new Hashmap(map);
map2.keySet().retainAll(keysToKeep);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking through all keys you could loop over the list and check if the HashMap contains a mapping. Then create a new HashMap with the filtered entries:

```
List<String> keys = Arrays.asList('a', 'c', 'e');

Map<String, String> old = new HashMap<>();
old.put('a', 'aa');
old.put('b', 'bb');
old.put('c', 'cc');
old.put('d', 'dd');
old.put('e', 'ee');

// only use an inital capacity of keys.size() if you won't add
// additional entries to the map; anyways it's more of a micro optimization
Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>(keys.size(), 1f);

for (String key: keys) {
    String value = old.get(key);
    if (value != null) newMap.put(key, value);
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `new` as variable name.

Comment: @Bubletan You are correct, renaming the variable to newMap.

Comment: @helpermethod you should use `new HashMap<> (keys.size(), 1f);`, otherwise a load fatcor of 0.75 will be used and the map may be resized once

Comment: `ìf (value != null)` is not a valid substitue for `containsKey` with HashMap. One could have written `hashMap.put("key", null)`, and then your `if (value != null)` test would be fooled. (Granted, this is such an frequent design at this point that setting a null value in a Map seems like a bad idea in the first place)

Comment: there are cases where you may want to store null values in your HashMap (you can still verify if it contains the key to disambiguate between a mapping with null or the absence of value for that specific key)... for example when you use it to cache results of computer intensive functions (where the result could be null)... so that would not work.

Answer (score 1):

You could even grow your own:

```
public class FilteredMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    // The map I wrap.
    private final Map<K, V> map;
    // The filter.
    private final Set<K> filter;

    public FilteredMap(Map<K, V> map, Set<K> filter) {
        this.map = map;
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        // Make a new one to break the bond with the underlying map.
        Set<Entry<K, V>> entries = new HashSet<>(map.entrySet());
        Set<Entry<K, V>> remove = new HashSet<>();
        for (Entry<K, V> entry : entries) {
            if (!filter.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                remove.add(entry);
            }
        }
        entries.removeAll(remove);
        return entries;
    }

}

public void test() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("1", "One");
    map.put("2", "Two");
    map.put("3", "Three");
    Set<String> filter = new HashSet<>();
    filter.add("1");
    filter.add("2");
    Map<String, String> filtered = new FilteredMap<>(map, filter);
    System.out.println(filtered);

}
```

If you're concerned about all of the copying you could also grow a filtered `Set` and a filterd `Iterator` instead.

```
public interface Filter<T> {

    public boolean accept(T t);
}

public class FilteredIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    // The Iterator
    private final Iterator<T> i;
    // The filter.
    private final Filter<T> filter;
    // The next.
    private T next = null;

    public FilteredIterator(Iterator<T> i, Filter<T> filter) {
        this.i = i;
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        while (next == null && i.hasNext()) {
            T n = i.next();
            if (filter.accept(n)) {
                next = n;
            }
        }
        return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        T n = next;
        next = null;
        return n;
    }
}

public class FilteredSet<K> extends AbstractSet<K> implements Set<K> {

    // The Set
    private final Set<K> set;
    // The filter.
    private final Filter<K> filter;

    public FilteredSet(Set<K> set, Filter<K> filter) {
        this.set = set;
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<K> iterator() {
        return new FilteredIterator(set.iterator(), filter);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        int n = 0;
        Iterator<K> i = iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            i.next();
            n += 1;
        }
        return n;
    }

}

public class FilteredMap<K, V> extends AbstractMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    // The map I wrap.
    private final Map<K, V> map;
    // The filter.
    private final Filter<K> filter;

    public FilteredMap(Map<K, V> map, Filter<K> filter) {
        this.map = map;
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return new FilteredSet<>(map.entrySet(), new Filter<Entry<K, V>>() {

            @Override
            public boolean accept(Entry<K, V> t) {
                return filter.accept(t.getKey());
            }

        });
    }

}

public void test() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("1", "One");
    map.put("2", "Two");
    map.put("3", "Three");
    Set<String> filter = new HashSet<>();
    filter.add("1");
    filter.add("2");
    Map<String, String> filtered = new FilteredMap<>(map, new Filter<String>() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(String t) {
            return filter.contains(t);
        }
    });
    System.out.println(filtered);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the clone() method on the K HashMap returned.

something like this:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MyClone {    
     public static void main(String a[]) {    
        Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> hashMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();    
        Map hashMapCloned = new HashMap<String, String>();    

        Map<String, String> insert = new HashMap<String, String>();

        insert.put("foo", "bar");
        hashMap.put("first", insert);

        hashMapCloned.put((HashMap<String, String>) hashMap.get("first").clone());

    }    
}
```

It may have some syntax errors because I haven't tested, but try something like that.

Comment: Prefer using supertype/interface for variable declaration instead of concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

No, because HashMap doesn't maintain an order of it's entries. You can use TreeMap if you need a sub map between some range. And also, please look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674669/how-to-get-a-submap-with-linkedhashmap); it seems to  be on the similar lines of yours.

Comment: I'm not interested in a specific range: just that the key belong to a specified  List.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a new `HashMap`. Since `HashMap` does not support structure sharing, there is no better approach than the obvious one. (I have assumed here that `null` cannot be a value).

```
Map<K, V> newMap = new HashMap<>();
for (K k : keys) {
    V v  = map.get(k);
    if (v != null)
        newMap.put(k, v);
}
```

If you don't absolutely require that new object created is a `HashMap` you could create a new class (ideally extending `AbstractMap<K, V>`) representing a restricted view of the original `Map`. The class would have two private final fields

```
Map<? extends K, ? extends V> originalMap;
Set<?> restrictedSetOfKeys;
```

The `get` method for the new `Map` would be something like this

```
@Override
public V get(Object k) {
    if (!restrictedSetOfKeys.contains(k))
        return null;
    return originalMap.get(k);
}
```

Notice that it is better if the `restrictedSetOfKeys` is a `Set` rather than a `List` because if it is a `HashSet` you would typically have O(1) time complexity for the `get` method.