# Filtering a map based on a list of keys

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a map like the following:

```
class Person {

    Long personId;
    String name;

    /*Getters and Setters*/
}
```

I have populated a map `Map<Long, Person> personMap = new HashMap<>();`

The key of the map is the personId itself.
I have a list of personIds like so,

`List<Long> coolPeople = new ArrayList<>();`

now I want to iterate through the map and get all the values with the keys corresponding the ids in the list `coolPeople`, and then store it in a List.

How can I achieve this in Java 8 optimally?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856781 for a similar problem

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It would be more efficient to iterate over the identifiers of the `List` and look them up in the `Map`, since search by key in a `HashMap` takes expected `O(1)` time, while the search in the `List` can take `O(n)` time at the worst case.

```
List<Person> people = 
    coolPeople.stream()
              .map(id -> personMap.get(id)) // or map(personMap::get)
              .filter(Objects::nonNull)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It should be: filter(Objects::nonNull) not map

Comment: @msayag Thanks, I mis-typed

Comment: @Eran You can also reduce `map(id -> personMap.get(id))` to `map(personMap::get)`

Comment: @Flown Good suggestion

Answer (score 9):

An alternative solution (and possibly more efficient - depending on the size of the map / list) would be to copy the map and act on the `keySet` directly:

```
Map<Long, Person> copy = new HashMap<> (personMap);
copy.keySet().retainAll(coolPeople);

Collection<Person> result = copy.values();
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this question looking for a way to filter the entries in a map using `stream()` and after reading the current answers I feel like this one is missing:

```
Map<String, String> result = myMap.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> { /* apply conditions for entry.getKey() and entry.getValue() here */})
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in returning a map, you could use the following:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> filterByKeys(final Map<K, V> map, final Iterable<K> keys) {
    final Map<K, V> newMap = new HashMap<>();
    keys.forEach(key -> Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key))
            .ifPresent(value -> newMap.put(key, value)));
    return newMap;
}
```

Comment: I think adding a usage example would make this answer more beneficial.

Answer (score -2):

Correct this :

```
List<Long> coolPeople = new ArrayList();
```

and for the other part :

```
List<Person> coolPersons=new ArrayList<Person>();
for (Long id:coolPeople) {
     Person p=map.get(id);
     coolPersons.add(p);
}
```

Feel free to comment if you are having any questions.